# Monit failing to start process

Tags: unix, debian, rvm, monit

I have a simple script that I'm trying to get Monit to monitor. After [some digging around](http://groups.google.com/group/rubyversionmanager/browse_thread/thread/d1a6c1f6396a8bf6/279b6dacdf898d0a?#279b6dacdf898d0a) I found this little nugget: `start program = "su - myuser -c '/home/user/myscript.rb start' "` which I believe should work but looking at the log files it says:

```
[PDT Oct 30 02:47:17] info     : 'simple_script' start: su
[PDT Oct 30 02:47:17] error    : Error: Could not execute su
```

Likewise earlier attempts only seem to read the part preceding a space so:

```
start program = "/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby /home/user/simple_script_daemon.rb stop"
```

results in…

```
[PDT Oct 30 03:09:49] info     : 'simple_script' start: /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby
```

Which doesn't fail like the first example but still seems to only execute the part preceding the space.

This is my full statement:

```
check process simple_script
    with pidfile /home/user/simple_script.rb.pid
    start program = "su - user -c '/home/user/simple_script_daemon.rb start' "
    stop program = "su - user -c '/home/user/simple_script_daemon.rb stop' "
    group simple_script
```

If you've got an idea what might be going on I'd love to hear from you!

Answer (score 7):

I guess you could try something like:

```
check process simple_script
    with pidfile /home/user/simple_script.rb.pid
    start program = "/home/user/simple_script_daemon.rb start" as uid user and gid user
    stop program = "/home/user/simple_script_daemon.rb stop" as uid user and gid user
    group simple_script
```

as stated in [monit doc](http://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#configuration_examples).

Comment: Hi Brice, after a _lot_ of fiddling around I've found that the following does it: start program = "/bin/bash -c 'export rvm_path=/home/user/.rvm; . $rvm_path/scripts/rvm; cd /home/user/crittr.me; $rvm_path/bin/rvm rvmrc load; ./simple_script_daemon.rb start'"   Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4):

You may need to provide full path to `su`, i.e. `/bin/su`